# How can I find the procedure or the query and the user who deleted from my table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Somehow every day I find out that some data are missing , there is a lot of jobs and applications that use this table, so I want to create a trigger and trace the time, the user and the stored-procedure that delete from my table, does anyone have knows how can I find the user and the SP ?

thank you in advance :)

Comment: user can be found by user_name(), suser_name()

Comment: also you can serarch your table name in `definition` column of `sys.sql_modules` to find all references

Comment: you need about whom deleted the rows or columns?

Comment: my table is referenced in 300 storedProcedure, so I created a trigger on my table and a new table to trace the change , Now I need whom deleted from my table to insert it into the new one and also if it a job I want the name of SP.

Comment: Thank you @MikhailLobanov, suser_name() is exactly what I need for the who deleted from my table :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can get a stored procedure name inside the trigger. User can be fetched with suser_sname() function.

```
declare @ExecStr varchar(1000);

CREATE TABLE #inputbuffer (
       EventType varchar(500)
       , Parameters varchar(500)
       , EventInfo varchar(4000)
);

SET @ExecStr = 'DBCC INPUTBUFFER(' + STR(@@SPID) + ')'

INSERT INTO #inputbuffer 
EXEC (@ExecStr)

SELECT EventInfo FROM #inputbuffer
```

Comment: Thank youuuuu , that exactly what I need :)